# c#: xsl:include when calling XslCompiledTransform.Load()

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

Good day,

I have another conundrum. Currently I have 2 `XSL` documents in my project's resource properties. One of the `xsl` documents includes the other with `<xsl:include>`

To make this short and simple, How can I force the `XslCompiledTransform` to include the document in the project's properties when calling the load method?

```
    public static string Transform(string xml)
    {
        var xsl = GetXsl();
        var writer = new StringWriter();
        var xpath = new XPathDocument(GetReader(xml));
        var xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        xslTransform.Load(GetReader(xsl)); // Fails here because it is looking for the included XSL elsewhere.
        xslTransform.Transform(xpath, null, writer);
        return writer.ToString();
    }

    private static XmlReader GetReader(string input)
    {
        var memstream = new MemoryStream();
        var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
        memstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        memstream.Position = 0;
        return XmlReader.Create(memstream);
    }

    private static string GetXsl()
    {
        return Properties.Resources.AppForms;
    }
```

Exception:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\myPc\Documents\.....\bin\utility.xsl'

As I mentioned, the two files are in the resources under the project's properties. The one loaded in the code above is `appforms.xsl`

Comment: If you have the XSLT in a string why do you need the GetReader method with a memory stream? You can simply create a StringReader over that string. As for the `GetXsl` method, I don't see that called in your code at all. You would need to set up a custom XmlUrlResolver that makes sure an include is read from the resources, there is no built-in support for that.

Comment: `var xsl = GetXsl();` is called. First line in Transform()

Comment: Sorry that I overlooked that, my mistake.

Comment: As for loading an include or import from a resource, you will need to use an overload of the `Load` method like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163427%28v=vs.110%29.aspx which allows you to pass in a custom XmlResolver that implements the loading from a resource.